# as_deref function doesn't change my concrete type

Tags: rust, option-type

I would like to convert my `Option<&String>` to `Option<&str>` with [`as_deref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_deref) but the compiler seems to misunderstand my intent. If I replace it with `.map(|e| e.as_str())` it works.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait SipField {
    fn from(&self) -> Option<&str>;
}

impl SipField for HashMap<String, Vec<String>> {
    fn from(&self) -> Option<&str> {
        self.get("from")
            .or_else(|| self.get("f"))
            .and_then(|i| i.first())
            .as_deref()
    }
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/lib.rs:9:9
   |
9  | /         self.get("from")
10 | |             .or_else(|| self.get("f"))
11 | |             .and_then(|i| i.first())
12 | |             .as_deref()
   | |_______________________^ expected `str`, found struct `std::string::String`
   |
   = note: expected enum `std::option::Option<&str>`
              found enum `std::option::Option<&std::string::String>`
```

Comment: Note that `as_deref` can convert an `Option<String>` into an `Option<&str>`, but you have an `Option<&String>` so the compiler takes the blanket [`impl<'_, T> Deref for &'_ T`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#impl-Deref-5) which converts an `Option<&String>` into an `Option<&String>`…

Comment: @Jmb Shouldn't two as_deref() work so ?

Comment: @Stargateur: If one `as_deref()` call converts an `Option<&String>` into an `Option<&String>`, two `as_deref()` calls will convert an `Option<&String>` into, well..., an `Option<&String>`.